# AWS Cognito: Is it possible to use same access token between multiple clients in the same pool

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, amazon-cognito

I am currently rewriting a legacy Django server with a Nest.js server and we are using AWS Cognito as identity provider but it seems like even though both servers are using the same User Pool ID, they are not accepting each other's access token as valid which would mean if we were to move our users from legacy server to Nest.js then all of the users would need to relogin to the app again which is not something we want of course. Is it possible to fix this? (I tried also both servers to use same client id but it did not helped)

This is how i check for JWT token in the Nest.js app:

```
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
    @Inject(CognitoConfig.KEY)
    cognitoConfig: ConfigType<typeof CognitoConfig>,
    private userRepository: UserRepository,
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      audience: cognitoConfig.appId,
      issuer: cognitoConfig.appAuthority,
      algorithms: ['RS256'],
      secretOrKeyProvider: passportJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: cognitoConfig.appAuthority + '/.well-known/jwks.json',
      }),
    });
  }

  // Used internally by Passport
  async validate(payload: any) {
    const user = await this.userRepository.get(payload.email);

    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException('User not found');
    }

    return user;
  }
```

Comment: Do the servers share the same app client ID? It is recommended to create new app clients for each platform: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-client-apps.html.

Comment: I tried both different and same client id per server and the result was the same, they did not accept each others tokens

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Hitting the same issue

Comment: Hi George, no i haven't i sadly accepted the loss and all of our users now needs to login to the app one extra time..

Comment: has anyone found a solution yet?